# application of Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm

Tags: python, dijkstra

I am applying [Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/), it works well with another examples, but I could not figure out why it does not give me the correct result for my example below [image]. Please give any help as quick as possible. Thanks a lot.

here is entire code. I think the shortest is 7 rather 5. Could you please help understand where I did wrong.

```
# Python program for Dijkstra's single
# source shortest path algorithm. The program is
# for adjacency matrix representation of the graph

# Library for INT_MAX
import sys


class Graph():

    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices
        self.graph = [[0 for column in range(vertices)] for row in range(vertices)]

    def printSolution(self, dist):
        print("Vertex \tDistance from Source")
        for node in range(self.V):
            print(node, "\t", dist[node])

    # A utility function to find the vertex with
    # minimum distance value, from the set of vertices
    # not yet included in shortest path tree
    def minDistance(self, dist, sptSet):

        # Initialize minimum distance for next node
        min = sys.maxsize

        # Search not nearest vertex not in the
        # shortest path tree
        for u in range(self.V):
            if dist[u] < min and sptSet[u] == False:
                min = dist[u]
                min_index = u

        return min_index

    # Function that implements Dijkstra's single source
    # shortest path algorithm for a graph represented
    # using adjacency matrix representation
    def dijkstra(self, src):

        dist = [sys.maxsize] * self.V
        dist[src] = 0
        sptSet = [False] * self.V

        for cout in range(self.V):

            # Pick the minimum distance vertex from
            # the set of vertices not yet processed.
            # x is always equal to src in first iteration
            x = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet)

            # Put the minimum distance vertex in the
            # shortest path tree
            sptSet[x] = True

            # Update dist value of the adjacent vertices
            # of the picked vertex only if the current
            # distance is greater than new distance and
            # the vertex in not in the shortest path tree
            for y in range(self.V):
                if self.graph[x][y] > 0 and sptSet[y] == False and dist[y] > dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]:
                    dist[y] = dist[x] + self.graph[x][y]

        self.printSolution(dist)


# Driver program
g = Graph(5)
g.graph = [[0, 2, 0, 4, 0],[0, 0, 2, 2, 0],[0, 0, 0, 2, 0],[0, 2, 0, 0, 1],[0, 3, 0, 0, 0]];
            # 0                 1                2                   3          4

g.dijkstra(0);
```

Output

```
g.dijkstra(0);
Vertex  Distance from Source
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    4
4    5
```

Comment: You mean, you think the shortest path from node 0 to node 4 has length 7? Why do you think that?

Comment: to go thorough the entire nodes, I think the shorest path is 0->1->2->3->4 , which has a length of 7

Comment: No, the shortest path is 0->3->4.

Comment: does not it have to go through the entire nodes?

Comment: No. That’s not what “shortest path” means. If you want a route through all the nodes, that’s the “travelling salesman problem”.

Comment: @Sneftel thank you so much for giving me the direction to work on

Comment: @Sneftel but in my application, the graph is directed, does TSP handles direction?

Comment: Yes, there’s nothing that requires undirected graphs.